# Is there an elegant way of overcoming TestNG's dependency injection shortcomings?

Tags: java, testng

In my experience, TestNG has been the most flexible testing Java framework. However, it does have some inconsistencies. The main one I've been running into is the lack of support for dependency injection in listeners and method selectors. This functionality is key when writing a re-usable testing harness that sits on top of TestNG. I was only able to come up with two ideas for workarounds (first one is a hack and the second one is a pain) , so I was wondering if anyone can think of a better way.

---

**First, the hacky way**

Create an enum representing a singleton

```
package com.example;
//other imports

public enum Injection {
  INJECTION

  private Injector guiceInjector;

  public void setGuiceInjector(final Injector guiceInjector) {
    this.guiceInjector = guiceInjector;
  }

  public void injectInto(final Object obj) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(this.guiceInjector).injectMembers(obj);
  }
}
```

Implement org.testng.IObjectFactory2 as follows

```
package com.example;

import static com.example.Injection.INJECTION;
//other imports

public final class GuiceBootstrap implements IObjectFactory2 {
  private final Injector injector;

  public GuiceBootstrap() {
    this.injector = Guice.createInjector(/*modules*/);
    INJECTION.setGuiceInjector(this.injector);
  }

  @Override
  public Object newInstance(final Class<?> kind) {
    return injector.getInstance(kind);
  }
}
```

Use the enum's `injectInto` as necessary, e.g.:

```
package com.example;

import static com.example.Injection.INJECTION;
//other imports

public final class SimpleRetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
  @Inject @MaxRetryCount private int maxRetries;
  private int retriesSoFar;

  public SimpleRetryAnalyzer() {
    INJECTION.injectInto(this);
    retriesSoFar = 0;
  }

  public boolean retry(final ITestResult result) {
    //implementation
  }
}
```

I despise mutable state in general, so I don't really consider this a valid approach. Furthermore, there's nothing that prevents the user of a test harness which leverages this approach from accessing the enum directly (even though it's *meant* to be internal). Hacky, unclean, involves mutable state...

---

**Second, the painful way**

Take control away from TestNG, and use it programmatically:

```
package com.example;

public CustomTestNgLauncher {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(determineGuiceModules(args));
    final ITestObjectFactory guiceObjectFactory = createGuiceObjectFactory(injector);
    final TestNG testNg = new TestNG();
    testNg.setObjectFactory(guiceObjectFactory);
    testNg.setOutputDirectory(reportsDirPathOrNull);
    testNg.setTestSuites(determineTestNgSuites());
    testNg.addListener(injector.getInstance(SomeCustomListener.class));
  }
}
```

In my opinion this is an improvement over the first approach, however the problem of injecting into method selectors still exists, because [TestNG#addMethodSelector](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/TestNG.html#addMethodSelector(java.lang.String,%20int)) takes in a `String` instead of accepting an instance of [IMethodSelector](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/IMethodSelector.html)...